# $.post to PHP file - callback not being hit till containing loop finished?

Tags: javascript, php, .post

I'm making a stock table, where the user can input a number of stock to issue out, and this function is to verify, for each member of the table, whether or not the quantity of stock in the database is sufficient to make the issue.

When I breakpoint through the code on Chrome, it seems to never hit the inside code of the $.post until after its finished looping through the table. And by then the data that is supposed to be passed to AddIssue just becomes 1 and 10 and nothing else.

It's starting to drive me mad, so I'd appreciate a pointer on what I'm doing wrong here

```
var issueArray =[];

function VerifyIssue()
{
    var numRows = document.getElementById("searchTable").rows.length - 2;
    var running = true;

    var str1 = "issue_";

    while(running == true)
    {
        if (numRows < 0 && running == true)
        {
            running = false;
            //insert code for success
            break;
        }
        else if (running == false)
        {
            break;
        }

        var str2 = numRows;
        var comb = str1.concat(str2);
        var issue_element = document.getElementById(comb);
        var q = issue_element.value;


        var i = issue_element.name;
        var idd = i.replace("issue_", "");
        var trimId = idd.trim();

        $.post
        (
            'includes/issueCheck.php',
            {
                id: trimId, 
                issueQuantity: q 
            },
            function(result)
            {
                alert(result);

                if (result < 0)
                {
                    alert("One of more quantities inputted are greater than held in stock");
                    running = false;
                }
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    addIssue(trimId, q);
                }
            }
        );
        numRows = numRows - 1;
    }
    alert(issueArray);
}

function addIssue(issueID, quant)
{
    var item = {};

    item.label = issueID;
    item.value = quant;
    issueArray.push(item);

}
```

This is the PHP that is called by the $.post

```
<?php
    $server = 'SQL2008';
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"rde_470585");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);

    $false = -1;
    $true = 1;
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $quantity = $_POST['issueQuantity'];
    $query = "Select Quantity FROM Stock WHERE StockID = ?";
    $param = array($id);
    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $param);
    $row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbQuantity = $row['Quantity'];

    if ($dbQuantity < $quantity)
    {
        echo $false;
    }
    else if($dbQuantity >= $quantity)
    {
        echo $true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you make a mistake with `break` instead of `continue`?

Comment: It's a bit offtopic but indenting your code will make it easier to read.

Comment: `$query = "Select Quantity FROM Stock WHERE StockID = ?";` was it your intention to use a question mark behind `StockID = ` instead of `$id` ?

Comment: @EdwardBlack You might want to read up on prepared statements :-)

Comment: @Kevinrob It looks a bit weird, but no it's supposed to be break. If it has reached less than 0 numRows and running hasn't been changed from true then it has reached the end and doesn't need to go round again.

Comment: @EdwardBlack No that's deliberate, like jeroen said it's part of prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry @Rickert I'm really bad for writing ugly, badly indented, code.

Comment: i fixed the indentation

Comment: @EdwardBlack haha thanks

Comment: Note: u should never access the superglobal $_POST array directly. Use a filter function instead e.g. `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");`

Answer (score 0):

Do you realise that your function(result){ ... } will only be called when the server response for your POST request is received? You have to build the code to take that delay into account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on this, reading up on Promises based on what @jojo said, but not sure if it's going to work for me.

How else can I make the javascript wait for a server response before resuming?